# How to use pd.apply with my own custom function that take 1 input argument

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

So I have a custom function that I want to apply to a row of data in a DataFrame, but how do I include the extra parameter that I need I have given an example below

```
# Using df.apply
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3]})
sum_A = np.sum(df.A)

def calc_weight(row, total):
    row["weights"] = row["A"]/total

df.apply(calc_weight(row, sum_A), axis = 1)
# Gives NameError: name 'row' is not defined

df.apply(calc_weight(row, sum_A), axis = 1)
# TypeError: calc_weight() missing 1 required positional argument: 'total'
```

The output that I want is something like:

```
  A weights
0 1  0.166 
1 2  0.333
2 3   0.5
```

I've looked online but I can't seem to find anything, or do I have to default to using a for loop to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add argument in apply function as below:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                  
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3]})                                                                                    
sum_A = np.sum(df.A)                                                                                                 

def f(a, total):
    return float(a)/total                                                                                            

df['weight'] = df['A'].apply(f, args=(sum_A,))                                                                       
print df
```

Output:

```
   A    weight
0  1  0.166667
1  2  0.333333
2  3  0.500000
```

~